# storing disabled button in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I code for a button that, when clicked, changes color (or disables it) and stays that way for all the next instances of that page?

This is how it currently looks like

```
function res1() {
var bgcolor = document.getElementById("hideshow").style.background = "gray";
var fontcolor = document.getElementById("hideshow").style.color = "white";
var text = document.getElementById("hideshow").innerHTML = "Reserved";

localStorage.setItem("hideshow").style.background.value = bgcolor;
localStorage.setItem("hideshow").style.color.value = fontcolor;
localStorage.setItem("hideshow").innerHTML.value = text;

document.getElementById("hideshow").style.background = bgcolor;
document.getElementById("hideshow").style.color = fontcolor;
document.getElementById("hideshow").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` can only store strings, so the idea is to store the state of each button you want to persist. To do this we can create a few simple functions:

- Save the state of a button to `localStorage`
- Retrieve the state of each button on load and set its state

```js
// Create a variable storing the buttons
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

// Retrieve the button state from localStorage and each
// button's state
const getBtnState = function (btns) {
  [].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem(btn.id) == 'disabled') {
      btn.disabled = true
    }
  });
};

// Add an event listener to each button to
// disable and store the button's state on click
[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
   btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     btn.disabled = true
     window.localStorage.setItem(btn.id, 'disabled')
   })
});

// Call the getBtnState function to set the initial state
// of each button
getBtnState(btns);
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="btn">Button 4</button>
```

This demo will not work on Stackoverflow due to the demo being 'sandboxed'. For a working demo head on over to this [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/LxPmRJ?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

Since your styles are hard-coded anyway, there is no need to also store them in localStorage.

Here's a simpler implementation:

```
document.onload = function(){
    if (localStorage.getItem("buttonHasBeenClicked")){
        // make the button grey and change text etc. here
        // also, you said you wanted to disable it?
        document.getElementById("hideshow").disabled = 'disabled';
    }
    document.getElementById("hideshow").addEventListener('click', function(e){
        localStorage.setItem("buttonHasBeenClicked",true);
    }
};
```

A side note on what you had:

```
localStorage.setItem("hideshow").style.background.value = bgcolor;
```

This will break because setItem doesn't return anything.  You pass in an object you want to store as the second parameter (i'm passing in the value true, above)